# Adding Result of editing video in one output file to export swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset, avmutablecomposition

Hi i am developing a video editor , I want to understand how can i combine outputs of editing options like trimming , playback speed together in one output file to export edited video , for eg in trimming i export avasset whereas for speed I export avmutablecomposition , now I want to understand how to combine these outputs, I am using avplayer in swift.

Comment: can you please share some codes and what type of editing you are done and what are libraries and framework are you using.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5135-how-to-play-record-and-merge-videos-in-ios-and-swift

Comment: @TusharKatyalI am making editor like iMovie , so i want to understand how can I recreate avmutablecomposition object after trimming video once to re-edit my video.

Comment: Thanks guys i solved it myself.